# using TOKENIZE in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to use the TOKENIZE function in PIG with a document that is comma separated. I would like to split on the commas, but NOT on white space. For example I would like for a list of 
(car, toy car, bunny) to be ((car), (toy car), (bunny) not ((car), (toy), (car), (bunny)). 
Is there a way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look to [STRSPLIT](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#strsplit) for splitting just on the comma?

(it works for CHARARRAY like TOKENIZE)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way,

You can try with Flatten operator as well

Example:

Input -> (a,(b,c))

B = foreach A generate $0 , flatten ($1)

Output -> (a,b,c)

**Use of Flatten and tokenize together**

You can read the word count problem [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_%28programming_language%29)